# Show mysql data - json encode while loop different format?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show some mysql data in a jquery dialog, this works just fine when I'm using this piece of code:

query:

```
 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
 $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var URL = data[3];              //get id
        var approved = data[4];           //get name

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>URL: </b>"+URL+"<b>  Status: </b>"+approved); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  });
```

When using this I'm getting this as result:

```
["1","peter","test.com","yes"]
```

this works, however there's more than 1 entry which I want to show so I'm doing this:

```
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE username='$username'");            //query
  while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {echo json_encode($array);
  }
```

which gives me the following result:

```
    {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"peter","username":"peter","2":"test.com","URL":"test.com","3":"yes","approved":"yes"}
{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"peter","username":"peter","2":"tessst.com","URL":"tessst.com","3":"yes","approved":"yes"}
```

Why is that ? Does it also fetch the row names (it seems like that) ?

What would I have to do to make this work / Get it in the same format so the output works?

Comment: `$outputArray = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
    array_push($outputArray, $row);
} echo json_encode($outputArray);`   Just found this, which makes the array look better, this is what it looks like now: `[{"id":"1","username":"peter","URL":"test.com","approved":"yes"},{"id":"2","username":"peter","URL":"tessst.com","approved":"yes"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Result of mysql_fetch_array($result) (instead of mysql_fetch_row($result)) has data both accessible via key and index (data["id"]=data[0], data["name"]=data[1], etc...).

You also give invalid JSON string to decoder, by echoing several valid strings without neither delimeters, nor enclosure ({...}{...}{...} instead of [{...},{...},{...}])